# spawning console sub process with different output

Tags: c#, process, console

I have a console application written in c# which starts a new process. This new process is also a console application. The problem is that whole child process output goes to parent console window and i don't want it to. It doesn't matter if it creates a new console window or not, I don't need it.

Edit:

```
Process p = new Process(); 
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\example.exe";
p.Start();
```

I tried some additional setting like CreateNoWindow, RedirectOutput and so on but with no luck

Comment: What code are you using to start the second console app?

Comment: What if you create a new `MemoryStream` and do a "RedirectOutput" to the memory stream? That way you have the output, but it *shouldn't* go to the screen of your original console window.

Comment: Can you show the code where your child process is configured and started? Normally a new console window would pop up and all output of the child process would end up in that window.

Comment: p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutpoot is just a bool property and changing it brings no effect, p.StandardOutput is a stream, but it's read-only

Comment: Is example.exe your own application? Or a third-party one? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you create a child process, a new console window pops up and all output of the child process ends up in that window. Here is a sample program that exhibits this behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST");

        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            Process.Start(path, "DontStartProcess");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```